Tabs spanning across multiple pages in a document
We are currently integrating docusign, we came accross a usecase of tabs like radio button and dropdowns spanning accross multiple pages. Does docusign allow this. If not is there any work around how we can handle this.
Thank you
For now I was going through the data models and documents where I found there is a page number attribute associated with tabs

One way to do that is to use HTML and responsive signing where there are no page limits and you place the tabs inside the HTML using special JSON markers.
You can read about how to use HTML for signing https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/
For your case you'll have something like :
  {{"groupName": "myRadio", "value": "radio1"}}
  {{"groupName": "myRadio", "value": "radio2"}}

NOTE: Page number is only associated with a tab if you use fixed positioning, but if you use anchor tabs - where you provide strings to find and place tags relative to these strings - you don't need to provide the page number at all.
